# Sahi - How to test web based application?

Tags: testing, automation, sahi

I installed Sahi on my MAC with firefox. Done the proxy configration and able to access localhost pages it supports. Sahi controller lauches fine and works well on INTRANET pages.

Now my application is web based application and i need Sahi controller to be working on INTERNET pages. I'm running into two problems - a) I can't access internet with proxy localhost:9999 settings and b) Sahi controller doesn't launch up on these internet web pages - i get connection refused.

Comment: can someone please explain why this question is given a negative vote......

Comment: Which version of Sahi you are using? Also provide some relevant information about the environment that you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any external proxy to connect to internet? If yes, you need to configure that proxy in Sahi.